# Want Jenkins pipeline script to create docker container with test database, test against, it, destroy container

Tags: node.js, git, postgresql, jenkins-pipeline

I've created a git repo for application (A) that contains a Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml that stands up a postgres database and creates and populates some tables. I use this as a support app for testing purposes during development as a disposable database.

I'd like to use this docker app in a Jenkins pipeline for testing my main application (B), which is a NodeJS app that reads and writes to the database. Application B is also in git and I want to use a Jenkins pipeline to run its tests (written in Mocha). So my overall pipeline logic would be something like this:

Triggering Event:
Code for application B is pushed to some branch (feature or master) to git.

Pipeline:

```
git checkout code for Application B (implicit)
git checkout code for Application A (explicitly)
cd to Application A directory:
docker-compose up -d  // start postgres container 
cd's to Application B directory: 
npm install 
npm run test (kicks off my Mocha tests that expect postgres db with localhost:5432 url)
cd to Application A directory 
docker-compose down  // destroy postgres container
// if tests pass, deploy application B
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure this. I'm really checking out code from *two* repos: The one I want to test and build, and another repo that contains a "support" application for testing, essentially mocking my real database.

Would I use a script or declarative pipeline?
The pipeline operates in a workspace directory for application B that is implicitly checked out when the pipeline is triggered. Do I just checkout the code for Application A within this workspace and run docker commands on it?